# Algorithm to check if a family contains two disjoint sets

Tags: disjoint-sets

Let $\mathcal F_1$ and $\mathcal F_2$ be a families of subsets of $\{1,\dots, m\}$. Such that $|\mathcal F_1| = n_1$ and $|\mathcal F_2|  = n_2$.

I would like to check if there is $f_1\in \mathcal F_1$ and $f_2\in \mathcal F_2$ with $f_1\cap f_2 = \varnothing$

One approach is to go through all $n_1n_2$ possible pairs and calculate the intersection for each one in $m$ time (or it can be $min(|f_1|,|f_2|)$ time but this doesn't matter to me).

Is there a faster way? reading the input would take $(n_1+n_2)m$ time. If there was anything of time $(n_1+n_2)^{2-\epsilon} p(m)$ where $p$ is polynomial that would be great.

Comment: Related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20278/5038.  Maybe try fast matrix multiplication algorithms?  Set $M_{ij} = 1$ if $j$ is in the $i$th subset; then compute $M M^\top$ via fast matrix multiplication.

Comment: Oh thank you very much !

Comment: Possibly also related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/7719/5038, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20285/5038